# Multi-Resolution occupancy grid maps data structure

Tags: c++, data-structures

Where can i find an implementation of the Multi-Resolution occupancy grid map . its used in game engines and a lot in robotics and comes under spatial data structures? is there a c++ / java library ?

Answer (score 2):

You can find Octomap here: http://octomap.sourceforge.net/